# loop and increment not working in unityscript

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, increment, unityscript, destroy

I'm having an issue with the hit cage function. I want to make it so after the cage gets over two times it gets destroyed. I've created a variable at the top which sets in to 0. I tried doing +=1 but that didn't work either. I also just tried doing hitCage++ and I debugged it and it stay at 1 with every hit. What have I done wrong?

```
function OnTriggerEnter2D(kill:Collider2D){

enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("enemy");
cage = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("cage");

if(kill.gameObject.tag == "enemy"){
Destroy(enemy);
Debug.Log("Dead It");
}

if(kill.gameObject.tag == "cage"){
for(hitCage = 0 ; hitCage > 2 ; hitCage++){
        if(hitCage > 2){
            Destroy(cage);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop isn't necessary. In fact, it's overwriting `hitCage` every time the function `OnTriggerEnter2D` is called.

```
function OnTriggerEnter2D(kill:Collider2D) {
    enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("enemy");
    cage = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("cage");

    if(kill.gameObject.tag == "enemy"){
        Destroy(enemy);
        Debug.Log("Dead It");
    }

    if(kill.gameObject.tag == "cage") {
        hitCage++;
        if(hitCage > 2) {
            Destroy(cage);
            hitCage = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Like I said in my question, I tried that and it didn't work. It wont destroy.

Comment: you might consider providing a little bit more for us to work with. when you switch to my code what happens to `hitCage` does it calculate properly? if so then it's not the count, if not then the count is still messed up and we'll have to figure out why. if you want help you'll need to put forth some effort.

Comment: Telling me to put forth effort is unnecessary. It's still doing the same thing, when I debug it it still says 1 with every hit. It's not incrementing.

Comment: when does `OnTriggerEnter2D` get fired? are we sure that `kill.gameObject.tag` is ever equal to `"cage"`? have you added gratuitous logging code to get a better idea of where things are going wrong? add logging code as i describe: in the first line of the function log "`OnTriggerEnter2D` fired" in the first line of the  `if` that checks for `"cage"` log "`kill.gameObject.tag = "cage"`" then report back with what you find.

Comment: With your code when I comment out this part: if(hitCage > 2) {} Everything works fine and the cage destroys and the increment works fine, it goes up 1234567 and so on, when I remove the uncomment it, hitCage remains at 1, the function is being called for sure but it won't increment that's why I tried the loop but it didn't work

Comment: where is `hitCage` defined? can you log `hitCage` right before the `if(hitCage > 2)` so we can see its value before anything happens to it?

Comment: public var hitCage:float = 0f;
This is defined at the top. When I log it before the if statement it says 0 then changes to 1. The script is attached to a prefab(arrow) which instantiates when a key is pressed(An arrow coming from a crossbow.)

Comment: added something to try to my answer, give it a shot. is there a reason you're using a float? can you use an integer? doesn't seem like it's the culprit but since you're dealing with whole numbers you don't really need to use a floating point. my update is based on the idea that we should increment `hitCage` prior to checking if it's over 2.

Comment: wait, are we sure that `OnTriggerEnter2D` is actually being fired more than once when it's not working? what i'm reading suggests that it may not. did you log when it's fired to confirm that even when it's not incremented, the function is still being fired more than once?

Comment: i downloaded unity and within 15 minutes i have a sphere that falls onto a cube, collides, bounces up until it reaches a certain height, falls back down, collides and after 2 collisions the sphere is destroyed. are you sure your "cage" object is tagged with "cage"? i really want to help you. if you wanna exchange code privately we can.

Comment: `Debug.Log(cage);` to make sure your `cage` object is properly obtained.

Comment: I logged the cage and when the arrow goes past it this comes up:cage (UnityEngine.GameObject)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
crossbow:OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D) (at Assets/scripts/crossbow.js:50). I think it is attained properly.

Comment: okay, then are you sure that one of the objects has `isTrigger` enabled? i mean this is really simple stuff and it's obviously not this code that's messing it up. i'm running the exact code i posted and it's working fine. it has to be your configuration of the objects involved.

Comment: I checked and yes it is enabled. I'm going to study my code further. It's got to be the configuration of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop isn't actually needed, OnTriggerEnter2D() is called when something enters the trigger. In this case you're telling your loop to go around twice once your object enters the trigger.

To quickly sort this problem you should change:

```
if(kill.gameObject.tag == "cage") {
    for(hitCage = 0; hitCage > 2; hitCage++) {
        if(hitCage > 2) {
            Destroy(cage);
        }
    }
}
```

To... (untested)

```
if(kill.gameObject.tag == "cage") {
    hitCage++;
    if(hitCage >= 2) {
        Destroy(cage);
    }
}
```

If you're up for a quick bit of constructive criticism to the structure you seem to have adopted, read below. If you're looking for the quick fix then don't worry too much but you may find it useful as your classes and objects increase in number.

It seems you're trying to make this class manage all of the damage and killing of everything. A better approach would be to give enemy a health counter and cage a health counter. Give them both public functions such as "takeDamage(damage:int)". Then this class you've given us would probably be a bullet or a sword or something. This means your sword (for example) would have a variable called something like "attackDamage". Then inside your sword class you would have this OnTriggerEnter2D() which picks up what the object is that has entered the trigger, and calls something like enemy.takeDamage(attackDamage).

Then inside your enemy or cage class all you need for takeDamage would be a check each time it takes damage to see if that knocks it down to 0 health. If so, then it would be destroyed.

Here's some example code (untested, I normally work in C# so you may need to modify a line or two slightly if I have my function names wrong).

Your enemy and cage classes will have this in them:

```
var health:int;

function Start () {
    health = 1;
}

function TakeDamage(damage:int) {
    //check we're not passing in a value of 0 or below
    if(damage > 0) {
        health = health - damage;
    }

    //If the enemy health is now 0
    if(health <= 0) {
        //Destroy the enemy
        Destroy(this);
    }
}
```

So now your enemy class and cage both have this function of TakeDamage() in them, they are now responsible for killing themselves and taking damage. This may be better because it means you could have a base class such as "AttackableEntity" which has TakeDamage() inside and then every object or class that you want to be Attackable would have this (there are better ways of structuring that kind of inheritance system).

Sword/Bullet (etc) class:

```
var attackDamage:int;

function Start() {
    attackDamage = 1;
}

function OnTriggerEnter2D(collider:Collider2D) {
    //get the gameObject that collided with us
    var theCollidedObject:GameObject = collider.transform.gameObject;

    if(theCollidedObject.gameObject.tag == "enemy") {
        //Get the Enemy script attached to the gameObject so that we can use TakeDamage()
        var enemy:Enemy = theCollidedObject.GetComponent<Enemy>();
        //make the enemy take damage equal to this objects attackDamage
        enemy.TakeDamage(attackDamage);
    }

    if(theCollidedObject.gameObject.tag == "cage") {
        var cage:Cage = theCollidedObject.GetComponent<Cage>();

        cage.TakeDamage(attackDamage);
    }
}
```

Now your class that is attacking is only responsible for finding what it's hit, and telling it to take damage equal to it's attack damage.

This is probably a bit better as it's clearer, and means if you have multiple enemies all acting differently, they manage their own health rather than your sword class having to manage all the health of the enemies.

It should also sort your problem of trying to decrement your cage by two before destroying it.

Answer (score 0):

You assign hitCage to be 0. Then you check if 0 is greater than 2...it's not, so we don't execute the for loop.